# App crashes when picking image with expo-image-picker

Tags: android, react-native, image, expo

I have an issue with my react native app.

I am using expo-image-picker to take a picture and send it to firebase.

Here is my issue:

When building the apk for my app and using it that way on the Android Emulator on Windows, the App crashes every time I take or choose a picture.

This does not happen when using the app through Expo Go.

Here is the android log error:

```
--------- beginning of crash
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime: Process: xxx.xxx.app, PID: 3450
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {xxx.xxx.app/xxx.xxx.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter mImageLoader
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5015)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter mImageLoader
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.imagepicker.exporters.CompressionImageExporter.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule.handleOnActivityResult(ImagePickerModule.kt:397)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule.onActivityResult(ImagePickerModule.kt:315)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.adapters.react.services.UIManagerModuleWrapper$4.onActivityResult(UIManagerModuleWrapper.java:165)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.onActivityResult(ReactContext.java:305)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(ReactInstanceManager.java:762)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.onActivityResult(ReactDelegate.java:90)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onActivityResult(ReactActivityDelegate.java:113)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.onActivityResult(ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt:103)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onActivityResult(ReactActivity.java:69)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8304)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5008)
02-09 11:13:42.098  3450  3450 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
02-09 11:13:42.098   540  3609 I am_crash: [3450,0,xxx.xxx.app,950582852,java.lang.NullPointerException,Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter mImageLoader,NULL,2]
02-09 11:13:42.100   540  3609 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity xxx.xxx.app/.MainActivity
02-09 11:13:42.100   540  3609 I wm_finish_activity: [0,196218990,9,xxx.xxx.app/.MainActivity,force-crash]
02-09 11:13:42.100   540  3609 I wm_focused_stack: [0,0,1,9,finish-top adjustFocusToNextFocusableStack]
02-09 11:13:42.101   540  3609 I wm_task_moved: [8,1,2147483647]
02-09 11:13:42.100   540  3780 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
02-09 11:13:42.101   540  3609 I wm_set_resumed_activity: [0,com.android.launcher3/.uioverrides.QuickstepLauncher,finish-top adjustFocusToNextFocusableStack]
02-09 11:13:42.109   314   314 D goldfish-address-space: claimShared: Ask to claim region [0x3f92ca000 0x3f9c2f000]
02-09 11:13:42.116   540  3609 I wm_pause_activity: [0,196218990,xxx.xxx.app/.MainActivity,userLeaving=false]
02-09 11:13:42.124   540  3609 I sysui_multi_action: [757,316,758,4,759,-1]
02-09 11:13:42.126   540   588 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
02-09 11:13:42.126   540   588 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
02-09 11:13:42.132  3450  3450 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 3450 SIG: 9
02-09 11:13:42.145  1032  1060 I droid.launcher: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
02-09 11:13:42.182  1032  1060 I droid.launcher: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 37.227ms
02-09 11:13:42.188   540   903 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{8b15932 u0 xxx.xxx.app/xxx.xxx.app.MainActivity}
02-09 11:13:42.191   298   298 I Zygote  : Process 3450 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
02-09 11:13:42.231   540   590 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) ActivityManager expire 3 lines
02-09 11:13:42.233   540   910 I ActivityManager: Process xxx.xxx.app (pid 3450) has died: prcp TOP 
02-09 11:13:42.233   540   910 I am_proc_died: [0,3450,xxx.xxx.app,200,2]
02-09 11:13:42.233   540   910 I am_uid_stopped: 10121
02-09 11:13:42.234  3660  3660 I ActivityThread: Removing dead content
```

Here is my code:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
const [status, requestPermission] = ImagePicker.useCameraPermissions();

  const pickImageFromCamera = async () => {
    requestPermission().then(async () => {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        quality: 0,
      });
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        setImage(result.uri);
      }
    });
  };

  const pickImageFromLibrary = async () => {
    requestPermission().then(async () => {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        quality: 0,
      });
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        setImage(result.uri);
      }
    });
  };
```

Here is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "XXX XXX",
    "slug": "XXXXXX",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./app/assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you add them to your placement instructions or reports."
        }
      ]
    ],
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "The app accesses your photos to let you add them to your placement instructions or reports.",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera",
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./app/assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
      ],
      "package": "xxx.xxx.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./app/assets/favicon.png"
    }
  },
  "infoPlist": {
    "UIUserInterfaceStyle": "Light"
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You are told that `parameter mImageLoader` is null. Check for null before use. Probably in setImage() which code you did not post

Comment: Thank you for your help, I posted `setImage()`. It just set the value of `image` using `useState()`

Comment: Then show us where you have mImageLoader variable.

Comment: I do not have a mImageLoader variable.I'm using react-native with expo to develop my app and using expo-image-picker to handle the Image picking.

Comment: You see that variable in the error message you posted? Follow it.

Comment: It is not image picking i think. But something you do using the picked uri. First find out which statement by removing statements.

Comment: Hi @VBAF2412 did you solved your problem ? I got the exact same.

Answer (score 2):

*Copying here the solution that worked for me [from William Alexander response on this github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15119#issuecomment-1000268968)*

This is occurring when `quality != 1` and `allowEditing: false`

The problem is mImageLoader is null.
The reason for this is ImageLoaderInterface cannot be found.
To fix that you need to

```
npm install expo-image-loader
```

expo-image-loader has that interface.

Then rebuild your .apk and it should be fine.

Thank you William !

Comment: Jesus! This was it! Thank you. Remember everyone to rebuild the project (eas build) just in case.